# Pandas reading colours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am making a program that will read aa excel document that will include names and colours (colors for the Americans), it needs to read the document and check if the name is what you entered and check if the colour of column C is green, yellow or red and add one to a score.

I know this is possible, but I don't know much about pandas and need some help and couldn't find much help from videos and other websites. Hopefully, you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Your post would be more fit on a freelancing website in my opinion. Nevertheless, you can learn more about how to read and manipulate Dataframes by checking out [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html). I think this function [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) would be useful for your project description

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name input needs to come from the command line, I'd do something like the following to get the name into the program:

```
name = sys.argv[1]
```

This uses the sys package to read the command line arguments. Sys.argv is a list of command line arguments.  By default, the first command line arg is the name of the executable you're running, so your first argument is the second element in the  argv list. You also could use the great [argparse package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)to do this.

Then to read it into pandas:

```
pd.read_csv(<path to csv here>)
```

I' assuming that you have a column named "name" and a column named "colour" for the following:

To get the rows of the dataframe that match the name:

```
df = df.loc[df["name"] == name]
```

The .loc method of dataframes is used to select rows based on a vaue or label. Here, the df["name"] == name checks to see if the name is the same as the name inputted.

Then to get a count of the numbers of colors (yep, I'm American) that match 'orange':

```
len(df.loc[df['colour'] == 'orange'])
```

this selects values from your dataframe (which has already been filtered to only include the name we're interested in) that match the color. Then once we have only those values, we can just use the length of the dataframe as the count of rows for that color.

For multiple colors you could wrap the above line of code that gets the count for one color in a for loop that iterates over a list of colors.

If you wanted to get a count for every name and color at once, I'd recommend a pandas group by:

```
df.groupby(["name", "colour"]).agg("count")
```

This groups your data frame first by the name, second by the color. Then it gets a count for each distinct name, color combination.

Comment: I don't understand any of this. Can you simplify this for me haha